# Why the review suspension?

Tags: discussion, review-suspension

https://diy.stackexchange.com/review/low-quality-posts/117415

I did this review yesterday. It was a new answer to an old question and was flagged. The person answering was a new contributor but seemed quite knowledgeable. I wrote a comment explaining what he should do but didn't want to mark delete. I thought it would be better if they had a chance to correct it themselves instead of checking in and finding it deleted so I marked it OK.

I really don't see how this action warranted a three day suspension.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is the post that you marked "Looks OK":

> I have no idea how any of this blog stuff works so please forgive me if I don't use the appropriate protocol... I'm old! lol I have a Challenger panel with a QFP2200T main breaker and need a replacement. I've been hearing horror stories and want some tea experience. I'm a degreed Eng and have a pretty huge b'ground in elec. I sat on a number of NEMA, NFPA, UL CSA and IEC committees so I understand quite a bit about this... but not experience with panel work. Any help would be greatly appreciated. BJ

While you left a comment asking them to post a new question, and thank you for that, choosing "Looks OK" was wrong because it's not an answer to the question. The Stack Exchange model works well because follow-up questions and other non-answers get removed, so that pages don't get filled up with "I've got that problem too..."

Also, marking it as OK can knock it out of the review queue, meaning that other reviewers wouldn't get to see it and help deal with it correctly.

Comment: Good points, no more Mr nice guy. How about  a suspended sentence.

Comment: Sentence suspended. Thanks for being reasonable about this.

Answer (score 5):

The review you provided on the post was that it "looks OK" despite the "answer" not answering the question and instead asking a question itself. In this case, flagging as "not an answer" would have been appropriate. Note that a deletion is not permanent, the OP can edit the post and flag for a moderator to reopen. But in this case, a question posted as an answer, that's unlikely and the OP should post a new question after looking at the tour and similar questions.

See also [this help section](https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/review-suspensions) on review suspensions.